# Horizontal lines showing up in volumetrics

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, volumetrics, lines

These horizontal lines keep appearing in my render(doesnt appear in viewport).
Incresing samples or volume bounces doesnt seem to fix it, Decreaing step rate doesnt aswell.
Currently rendering in CUDA since Optix threw an "OSL group size data greater" error[image]

Any help is appreciated